# For loop is killing browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, canvas

I am trying to loop through the array that is returned by the canvas method: getImageData() which returns the pixels color values for an image drawn to an HTML canvas. But I am killing my browser, the array returned is quite large for the average sized image of course, am I using the wrong approach or is looping through such a large array just not going to be possible?

```
for (var i = 0; i < ImageData.length; i + 3) {
    if (ImageData[i] > 210 && ImageData[i + 1] < 200 && ImageData[i + 2] > 60) {
        var Suspect = {
            Red: ImageData[i],
            Green: ImageData[i + 2],
            Blue: ImageData[i + 3]
        }
        Suspects.push(Suspect);
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `i + 3` in `i+= 3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're never incrementing `i` with the statement `i+3`. You need to assign the result back to `i`: `i = i+3` or `i += 3`.

Also notice that for [`ImageData.data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) the usual step width is 4, not 3; every fourth value in the array is the [alpha channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_channel) (opacity) of the pixel.

Answer (score 2):

Of course this is culling the browser. `i` is `0` and will always remain 0... So you have yourself a deadlock.

```
i+3
```

is an expression, that evaluates to 3, but `i` isn't re-assigned/incremented, write `i += 3`

Answer (score 0):

The browser goes in a deadlock because i remains '0' always. you should change in the for loop `i+3` to `i+=3`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ImageData.length; i += 3) {
    if (ImageData[i] > 210 && ImageData[i + 1] < 200 && ImageData[i + 2] > 60) {
        var Suspect = {
            Red: ImageData[i],
            Green: ImageData[i + 2],
            Blue: ImageData[i + 3]
        }
        Suspects.push(Suspect);
    }
}
```